# Regex to wrap JSON property value inside another string. MongoDB transition

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I'm trying to insert some data from a proprietary JSON database into MongoDB for testing purposes. My data is currently in a json file in the format:

```
{ "_id": "213124123114",
  "foo":bar",
  "otherId": "2324242424",
  ...
}
```

To keep my test data relationships intact, I want to use sed to wrap all the _id and xxxId values with ObjectId(...)

My data would then look like:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("213124123114"),
  "foo":bar",
  "otherId": ObjectId("2324242424"),
  ...
}
```

I would then take the data and insert it into mongo in the same format as displayed in the file.

I'm testing my regex in javascript, but the following assignment blows up:

```
var y = s/"_id":(\s?"[0-9]+"),/ObjectId($1)/gi
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Escaping the ':' doesn't seem to do anything.

When I remove the capture flag at the start, the regex assignment works as expected

```
var y = /"_id":(\s?"[0-9]+"),/
var p = "\"_id\": \"123123123121321212312\",";
y.test(p) === true
```

but I have no way to capture the value block I need to wrap.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `sed` instead of properly parsing and emitting JSON?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to read in the JSON with a JSON parser, then manipulate it?

Comment: Possibly so, but it was the recommendation of a senior coworker. He was certain going the sed route would be faster.

Comment: And, frankly, I would like to at least learn how to do it with sed before falling back to what I know :)

Comment: Just in case anyone else tries this, it turns out that just wrapping the _id value in ObjectId(..) is not good enough for insertion into mongodb. It's best to blank out the _id entries, and then re-hook-up your records with a script afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
json.replace(/("(?:_id|otherId)": ?)("\d+")/g, '$1ObjectId($2)');
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WJBm/1/